# Restart conversation functionality in IBM Watson Assistant Web Chat

Tags: ibm-watson

I'm looking to add the "restart conversation" functionality to my wordpress website. How might I go about doing so? Right now, I got this screenshot from the web chat function settings on Watson Assistant.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can put `<? context.clear() ?>` and `<? clearDialogStack() ?>` to the response to Watson (in the backend).

Another option to configure on node which will clear and jump to beginning. But to call this node you should give some condition ex.: `input_text == "SYSTEM_CLEAN"` and respond to Watson with word "SYSTEM_CLEAN"